# Drop down list and gridview color

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, dropdown

OK, I got some help earlier this week in highlighting a cell in GridView based on conditions.

Now, I want to add a drop down list to a column status (done or not done).  I got it to work, but I don't know how to change the color once the field is updated with new user input.

I tried using the below code to do it, but I'm guessing I need to call the DDL or template?

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

I still don't have any luck with this.  It looks like when the status field is updated via dropdownlist, it doesn't interpret the new data (autopostback is set to true.)  Basically, it thinks that the value is still "null".  Any ideas?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="SID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnDataBound="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SID" HeaderText="SID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Servers" HeaderText="Servers" SortExpression="Servers" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem>done</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>not done</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[3].Text == "done")
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
        }
        else if (row.Cells[3].Text == "not done")
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you need to handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the DropDownList, not the GridView. You will then use similar logic to what you already have, but find the GridViewRow based on the DropDownList that changed.

Make sure your DropDownList will handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Remember that DropDownLists do not automatically cause a post back unless told to.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>' 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="True">
```

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;

    if(ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "done")
    {
        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
    }
    else if(ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "not done")
    {
        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code, but its only highlighting the row color when you go to edit the gridview.  I want it to highlight the row to reflect the changes after the user update the record via dropdownlist.

Comment: I don't totally understand what you mean. You want to highlight the row when the user changes the selection in the DropDownList?

Comment: Note that the way your GridView is laid out is saying that the DropDownList is _only_ shown when the GridView is in edit mode.

Comment: Well the gridview has a the status column.  User can edit the status via a dropdownlist within the gridview for the status column.  Once its updated the records that is being displayed should be highlighted based on the status.

Comment: Right, and when they do so, the row should change color, correct? That is what the code I wrote is meant to do. Should the color change at other times as well?

Comment: Well, the code provided only highlights the row when I go to click edit within the gridview, but not once the record is updated and viewed.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You need to set `AutoPostBack="True"` on the DropDownList. Sorry, I didn't see that at first.

Comment: I did that, and no luck.

Comment: OK, I'm not totally sure what isn't working for you then. I tried this code myself and it works as expected.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that.  I'll take a look at my code again.  Thanks for the help. I'll keep this post updated if I figure it out.